# What does "pull the trigger" mean in football (soccer)?

Tags: phrase-meaning

What does "pull the trigger" mean in football (soccer)?

11' Donald Love almost opened the scoring with a cracker! Pulled the trigger as he raced down the right flank and his effort sailed narrowly over the top! Moments later Gooch tries his luck but his ball flashed across the face of goal and wide.

Answer (score 3):

To shoot the ball in soccer means to kick the ball. To shoot a gun is to pull the trigger. So this is just another way of saying: to kick the ball.

Football commentators can use colorful language. This is just one example of it. It is not a football "term" per se.

Comment: I immediately picked up on the *Christmas cracker / firecracker* allusions with OP's example, but I can honestly say that in all my years I've never been consciously aware of the *shoot / gun* connection in relation to shots at goal. It's true we might also say *He **fired** the ball into the back of the net*, but directly-related ***booted*** and indirectly-related ***hammered*** are both probably more likely in that exact context.

Comment: cracker, rather than an allusion to Christmas cracker, is from the sense of "crack"="the best" (eg a crack shot), from earlier verbal sense "crack" meant "do with quickness".

Comment: @James K: I did provide that definition (with a link) in my own answer. Obviously we don't necessarily expect *deliberate* allusions to broader contexts like that in a sports commentary (as opposed to carefully-constructed literary / poetic text), but that hardly "invalidates" my *perception* of the broader context. Post-modernism ("The text is all") established that principle long ago - it's what you *read* that counts, not what the author wrote.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Do you ever listen to Ray Hudson? He  builds all sorts of metaphors into his commentary. The same goes for commentators in Spanish. Read this and then take a listen to the podcast: https://www.si.com/soccer/2018/01/11/ray-hudson-announcer-podcast-bein-sports-barcelona-real-madrid

Comment: There is no conscious connection. There is merely a twitter feed that uses the expression: pull the trigger. There is no **gun**. I am just explaining what pull the trigger means in English. Here is shoot: https://www.sportsessionplanner.com/s/yGlQ/being-aggressive-dribble-shield-shoot-to-score-goals.html

Comment: Pull the trigger: fired off a shot (i.e. kicked the ball) and in this case missed.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Actually I noticed that, and I thought I'd deleted that comment. . .

Comment: It seems natural enough to use metaphors like *fire the starting gun* (or even *kick off*) in relation to "starting/opening hostilities" in the context of a football match. But I still think *pulled the trigger* is a somewhat clumsy / quirky usage in OP's context. Not really something to file away for possible future use by learners.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I said it was not a football term. And I never suggested it should be filed away. However, it is good for  people learning English to learn that not everything is "already written".

Comment: *Please* stop assuming that every comment I make is intended to refute something you've said. I simply reiterated my point for the benefit of learners who might otherwise assume that if *pulling the trigger* isn't specifically a football idiom, it might still be appropriate in more general contexts. But this isn't really true except for the much more specific meaning where it's used to identify one individual among many attackers as the "proximate cause" of a fatality / dramatic event.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I disagree with that. And not all references to pulling a trigger are necessarily bad. Pull a trigger is pull a trigger. A person could be skeet shooting or doing that Olympic shooting thing, pretty vanilla activities, after all.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a football-related idiom at all. It's effectively just a "one-off" usage.

Actually, to me it comes across as something of a bungled "mixed metaphor", because I understand ***cracker*** as alluding to [*Christmas cracker*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christmas_cracker) and [*firecracker*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/firecracker) (as well as the idiomatic slang usage [***cracker*** = thing that is very good](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/cracker)). But Christmas crackers don't have triggers (two people pull them apart, one from each end, to "detonate" them), and firecrackers have fuses, not triggers.

Perhaps I'm a bit harsh. But all the writer means is the player *started the play / attempt to score*. Metaphorically, he suddenly / unexpectedly started to unleash his "offensive / attacking" power (his playing skills), the way one might *pull the trigger / open fire* with an actual offensive weapon (gun).

Comment: Yes, I believe I said it was not a football term . It is just colorful language. Donald Love attempted to score a goal.

Comment: @Lambie: Indeed. We were obviously comnposing our answers at the same time. If yours had already been there with *It is not a football "term" per se* I wouldn't have started writing. But since we both make slightly different additional observations, I decided to let mine stand after I saw yours.